# Set property in nested object using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to set Address1 in obj1 using reflection and I can't figure out how to get a reference to the correct object. I'm not sure how to get a reference to the Address1 instance to pass into the first parameter of SetValue()

**Round 1:**

```
public class StackOverflowReflectionTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SetDeepPropertyUsingReflection()
        {
            var breadCrumb = ".Addresses[0].Address1";

            var obj1 = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Eric",
                Addresses = new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address() {Address1 = "123 First Street"}
                }
            };

            var newAddress1 = "123 Second Street";

            var propNames = breadCrumb.Split(".");
            for (var index = 0; index < propNames.Length; index++)
            {
                var propName = propNames[index];
                if (propName.Contains("["))
                {
                    var propNameToGet = propName.Substring(0, propName.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                    var prop = obj1.GetType().GetProperty(propNameToGet);
                    var leftBrace = propName.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    var rightBrace = propName.IndexOf("]", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    var position = int.Parse(propName.Substring(leftBrace + 1, rightBrace - leftBrace - 1));

                    var propNameToSet = propNames[index + 1];


                    var propToSet = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[position].GetProperty(propNameToSet);
                    propToSet.SetValue(obj1, newAddress1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO: deal with different types
                }
            }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
           public string Address1 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

---

**Round 2** based on Ed's feedback, still stuck on how to get the value on this line: var value = property.GetValue(obj, new object[] { indexPart });

```
  public class StackOverflowReflectionTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SetDeepPropertyUsingReflectionRound2()
        {
            var breadCrumb = "Addresses[0].Address1";

            var obj1 = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Eric",
                Addresses = new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address() {Address1 = "123 First Street"}
                }
            };

            var newAddress1 = "123 Second Street";

            SetPropertyValueByPath(obj1, breadCrumb, newAddress1);
        }

        public bool CrackPropertyName(string name, out string namePart, out object indexPart)
        {
            if (name.Contains("["))
            {
                namePart = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal));

                var leftBrace = name.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var rightBrace = name.IndexOf("]", StringComparison.Ordinal);

                indexPart = name.Substring(leftBrace + 1, rightBrace - leftBrace - 1);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                namePart = name;
                indexPart = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
        {
            if(CrackPropertyName(name, out var namePart, out var indexPart))
            {
                var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(namePart);
                var value = property.GetValue(obj, new object[] { indexPart });
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
            }

        }

        public void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object newValue)
        {
            var property = typeof(Address).GetProperty(name);
            property.SetValue(obj, newValue);
        }

        public void SetPropertyValueByPath(object obj, string path, object newValue)
        {
            var pathSegments = path.Split(".");

            if (pathSegments.Length == 1)
            {
                SetPropertyValue(obj, pathSegments[0], newValue);
            }
            else
            {
                ////  If more than one remaining segment, recurse

                var child = GetPropertyValue(obj, pathSegments[0]);

                SetPropertyValueByPath(child, String.Join(".", pathSegments.Skip(1)), newValue);
            }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
           public string Address1 { get; set; }
        }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
public class StackOverflowReflectionTest
    {
[Fact]
        public void SetDeepPropertyUsingReflectionSolution()
        {
            var breadCrumb = "Addresses[0].Address1";

            var obj1 = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Eric",
                Addresses = new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address() {Address1 = "123 First Street"}
                }
            };

            var newAddress1 = "123 Second Street";

            SetPropertyValueByPath(obj1, breadCrumb, newAddress1);
        }

        public bool CrackPropertyName(string name, out string namePart, out object indexPart)
        {
            if (name.Contains("["))
            {
                namePart = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal));

                var leftBrace = name.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var rightBrace = name.IndexOf("]", StringComparison.Ordinal);

                indexPart = name.Substring(leftBrace + 1, rightBrace - leftBrace - 1);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                namePart = name;
                indexPart = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
        {
            if(CrackPropertyName(name, out var namePart, out var indexPart))
            {

                var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(namePart);
                var list = property.GetValue(obj);
                var value = list.GetType().GetProperty("Item").GetValue(list, new object[] { int.Parse(indexPart.ToString()) });
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return obj.GetType().GetProperty(namePart);
            }

        }

        public void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object newValue)
        {
            var property = typeof(Address).GetProperty(name);
            property.SetValue(obj, newValue);
        }

        public void SetPropertyValueByPath(object obj, string path, object newValue)
        {
            var pathSegments = path.Split(".");

            if (pathSegments.Length == 1)
            {
                SetPropertyValue(obj, pathSegments[0], newValue);
            }
            else
            {
                ////  If more than one remaining segment, recurse
                var child = GetPropertyValue(obj, pathSegments[0]);

                SetPropertyValueByPath(child, String.Join(".", pathSegments.Skip(1)), newValue);
            }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
           public string Address1 { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't do anything like what I think you're assuming.

What you want here is recursion. Given `”Foo.Bar[1].Baz”`, get `Foo`. Get `Bar[1]` from that. Get the PropertyInfo from `Baz` from its parent, use that to set the value of the `Baz` property of the `Bar[1]` property of `Foo`.

To break it down:

1. Write a method that "cracks" a property name and uses out parameters to return both the name part and the index value part: `"IndexedProperty[1]"` goes in; "IndexedProperty" and integer `1` come out. `"FooBar"` goes in, `"FooBar"` and `null` come out. It returns true if there's an indexer, false if not.

   ```
   bool CrackPropertyName(string name, out string namePart, out object indexPart)
   ```
2. Write a method that takes an object, and a string "PropertyName" or "IndexedPropety[0]" (not a path -- no dot) and returns the value of that property on that object. It uses `CrackPropertyName()` to simplify its job.

   ```
   object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
   ```
3. Write a method that sets a property value by name (not by path, just by name). Again, it uses `CrackPropertyName()` to simplify its job.

   ```
   void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object newValue)
   ```
4. A recursive method using the above:

   ```
   void SetPropertyValueByPath(object obj, string path, object newvalue)
   {
       var pathSegments = /* split path on '.' */;

       if (pathSegments.Length == 1)
       {
           SetPropertyValue(obj, pathSegments[0], newValue); 
       }
       else
       {
           //  If more than one remaining segment, recurse

           var child = GetNamedPropertyvalue(obj, pathSegments[0]);

           return SetPropertyValueByPath(obj, String.Join(".", pathSegments.Skip(1)), newValue);
       }
   }
   ```

These methods are all pretty trivial. Since you're using reflection anyway, you may as well go whole hog and write one non-generic method that sets any property of anything.

Comment: I added a round 2, struggling with this line: var value = property.GetValue(obj, new object[] { indexPart });

Comment: Give me a little more time, I think I figured out the problem.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks everyone and a shout out to Ed for the "whole hog" solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reflection to get the value of the `Addresses` property from an instance of `Person` you would do this:

```
 var myPerson = new Person()
        {
            Name = "Eric",
            Addresses = new List<Address>()
            {
                new Address() {Address1 = "123 First Street"}
            }
        };  
var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty("Addresses");
var addresses = (IList<Address>) property.GetValue(myPerson );
```

First you're finding the property - an instance of `PropertyInfo` - which belongs to the `Person` type. Then you're retrieving the value of that property for a specific instance of `Person`, `myPerson`.

`addresses` is an `IList<Address>` so there's not much use in using reflection to get a particular `Address` from the list. But if for some reason you wanted to:

```
private Address GetAddressAtIndex(IList<Address> addresses, int index)
{
    var property = typeof(IList<Address>).GetProperty("Item");
    var address = (Address) property.GetValue(addresses, new object []{index});
    return address;
}
```

This is essentially the same as the first example, except that in this case the property (`Item`) requires an index. So we use the overload of `GetValue` that accepts one or more indexes.

Now you've got an instance of `Address`. I'm doing each of these in separate steps because they are all separate steps. There's no one step that will perform the entire operation.

If you have an instance of an address and you want to use reflection to set the `Address1` property:

```
private void SetAddress1OnAddress(Address address, string address1Value)
{
    var property = typeof(Address).GetProperty("Address1");
    property.SetValue(address, address1Value);
}
```

Very similar. You're first retrieving the `Address1` property and then calling its `SetValue` method to set the value on a specific instance if `Address`.

Comment: I'll add a caveat, which is that 95% of the time if you find yourself having to do this, something has gone wrong and you're having to break the emergency glass. If you're using reflection it means that you don't know what type of object you have. Except you do know what type of object you have or else you wouldn't know what property to look for. But like your class name indicates (`StackOverflowReflectionTest`) you're just experimenting. It's helpful understand in case you have to read someone else's code.

Comment: To give you a full rundown of what I'm trying to do. I have a Xamarin app with offline capabilities that has a background service that syncs data every five minutes. When a sync occurs, I need to propagate those changes to the UI, unfortunately, the shape of the ViewModels is much different than the table structures in SQLite, so the idea is the fire an invalidate message to the UI, have it requery its data from SQLite, and do a deep compare to find the differences and update the models accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the quick and dirty I put together in LINQPad that changes the Address1 property of the object you have defined.

```
void Main()
{
    var obj1 = new Person()
    {
        Name = "Eric",
        Addresses = new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address() {Address1 = "123 First Street"}
                }
    };

    var index = 0;

    var addressList = typeof(Person)
             .GetProperty("Addresses")
             .GetValue(obj1);

    var address = addressList.GetType()
             .GetProperty("Item")
             .GetValue(addressList, new object[]{index});

    address.GetType()
             .GetProperty("Address1")
             .SetValue(address,"321 Fake Street");

    Console.WriteLine(obj1.Addresses[index].Address1); // Outputs 321 Fake Street
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}
```